# For loop iteration on pandas dataframe - improve time

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization

I have table similar to this tabke, which shows the payments individuals. I have already built a script to create my required output table, but I would like optimize my script to run more efficient and faster. This is my original table:

```
index     city         name          time                 spent_amount
0         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-01 09:08:00    22
1         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-01 13:32:00    35
2         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-01 16:16:00    5
3         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-02 09:24:00    19
4         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-02 12:43:00    25
5         New York     Donas Belik   2021-09-02 15:26:00    7
6         New York     Lily Perlbug  2021-09-01 08:12:04    103
7         New York     Lily Perlbug  2021-09-01 21:52:00    17
...
x         Berlin       Max Arling    2021-09-01 10:12:00    43
```

I have written a script that runs on this table and does the following steps:

1. Gets unique list of cities
2. get list of unique names
3. for loop- get **only specific name each time**
4. get list of **unique dates** (ignore hours) of each person
5. nested for loop- get dataframe of specific person in **specific date**
6. calculate for the filtered dataframe: maximum daily spent, minimum daily spent and average daily spent.
7. append these values for list
8. create dataframe with columns: person name, date, max,min and mean.

The code I use for this is the following:

```
maxes=[]
mins=[]
means=[]
namess=[]
datess=[]

names=df['city'].unique().tolist()


for n in names:
    tmp=df[df['name']==n]
    
    dates=tmp['date'].dt.date.unique().tolist()
    dates=[str(x) for x in dates]
    
    
    for d in dates:
        
        tmp1=tmp[tmp['date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").eq(d)]
        
        val_max=tmp1['Data'].max()
        val_min=tmp1['Data'].min()
        val_mean=tmp1['Data'].mean()
        
        maxes.append(val_max)
        mins.append(val_min)
        means.append(val_mean)
        datess.append(d)
        namess.apppend(n)
        
temperature_data=pd.DataFrame(zip(namess,datess,means,maxes,mins),columns=['name','date','mean temp','max temp','min temp'])
```

My end goal is to **optimize this for loop to make it run faster and maybe write it more estetically.**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `groupby` instead? You `groupby` "city", "name" and "date" and find the max, min and mean of "spent_amount":

```
out = (df.groupby(['city', 'name', df['time'].str.split().str[0]])['spent_amount']
       .agg(['max', 'min', 'mean']).add_suffix(' temp').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
       city          name        time  max temp  min temp  mean temp
0    Berlin    Max Arling  2021-09-01        43        43  43.000000
1  New York   Donas Belik  2021-09-01        35         5  20.666667
2  New York   Donas Belik  2021-09-02        25         7  17.000000
3  New York  Lily Perlbug  2021-09-01       103        17  60.000000
```